# Interstellar transport by death

Tags: story-identification

I remember this as a book or series of books, from the 90's or before.

The technology developed over time, but at the beginning of the book/series the only way to be transported throughout the galaxy was for someone in one location to die, and someone in another location to be transported into their body... just their mind, etc., they leave their own body behind.

The only other story I remember from the book/series was of a girl, whose brother was injured after buying a laser axe which hadn't been paid for, so she had to do the transport thing.

Comment: *Cluster* by Piers Anthony?

Comment: The second story is *Thousandstar* from the same series.  One of the two protagonists, Jessica of Capella, impersonates her brother to take part in an interstellar contest after he is badly injured.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Sounds like an answer to me

Comment: Thousandstar is definitely the second story. It has the laser axe mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one seems to want to take credit for the answer, so I will agree that it is *[Thousandstar](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/617248.Thousandstar)* by Piers Anthony, fourth book of the *Cluster series*.

[image: Front cover of Thousandstar]

> At the edge of the Milky Way, the treacherous space race for the legacy of the Ancients begins - a race against time, enemy aliens, and black holes. For outlawed hero Heem of Highfalls and beautiful Jessica of Capella, the extraordinary contest is very simple: They can win or they can die.

For the sibling pair and the accident (apparently with a saw, not an ax):

> Jessica is a blue, royal clone of a brother on Capella who are rapidly going bankrupt. Her brother devises a scheme to get them solvent quickly and it involves a quick, but possibly dangerous 10-day mission for him off planet. The two are so alike, they share virtually identical “auras,” and others don’t realize there are two of them. Shortly before he is to leave on his mission, he has an accident with a saw, begs Jessica to kill him and go on his mission for him, which horrifies her, but to do it to keep the family solvent and to keep it going into the future, so she does kill him and does exactly that – enter the contest, which is the mission.

Comment: For the record, I've just double-checked and the second review you quote is inaccurate - Jessica refuses to kill her brother, and that is why she needs to impersonate him and go on the mission in his place.

Comment: For the record, I didn't quote the review. A nice editor added it :)